# iOS DJI Pilot App no option to connect to device

Tags: dji, smartphone-app

I just got a DJI Mavic 3 Enterprise Multispectral (M3M) for work and am learning how to use it.

I download all of the DJI apps on the iPhone App Store, and the only one compatible with my drone supposedly is the "DJI Pilot" app. (I notice that there is no "DJI Pilot 2" app on the appstore...) However, I see absolutely no option to connect my device to the app and cannot figure out how to do so…

[image]

Is anyone else having this problem? Where are they cannot even find an option to connect to their drone through the DJI Pilot iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently there is no phone app for the Mavic Enterprise models at this time. Here is DJI's response:

> Dear Customer，
> Thank you for contacting DJI Technical Support. On the App Store, there is not an APP for the M3M, because the M3M is using the pilot 2 APP which is built into your RC. Here is the only software which is mentioned on our download center for the computer: DJI Assistant 2 for MG

Here is a [link](https://www.dji.com/downloads/products/mavic-3-m) they provided listing the specific software available for the product